# Making SKPhysicsBody impenetrable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, collision, sprite-kit

I am having trouble making my wall physics body impenetrable. If my player node physics body collides with the wall at a slow "speed", it stops. However, if it goes at fast "speed" it goes through the wall. My player is moved by a `PanGestureRecognizer`. By speed, I basically mean if there is a sudden "fast" swipe or if the gesture is not a decently slow moving pan gesture, then the player goes through the wall.  These are my node properties:

```
  self.player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.player.size];
  self.player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = SVGPlayerCategory;
  self.player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = SVGWallCategory;
  self.player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = SVGWallCategory;
  self.player.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
  self.player.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
  self.player.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

        self.leftWall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.leftWall.size];
        self.leftWall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = SVGWallCategory;
        self.leftWall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = SVGPlayerCategory;
        self.leftWall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = SVGPlayerCategory;
         self.leftWall.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
         self.leftWall.physicsBody.resting = YES;
```

If it helps, this is my move method:

```
-(void)dragPlayer: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

        CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

        SKAction *move =  [SKAction moveByX:translation.x y:-translation.y  duration:0];
        [self.player runAction:move];
        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
    }
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally in a purely physics driven world enabling precise collision detection would suffice.

However since you allow the user to position the body, there's nothing preventing the user from setting the body's position to somewhere inside the wall or simply skipping the wall altogether. Then Box2D's contact resolution steps in and moves the body outside the collision, which depending on where the body was placed within the wall will result in the body being moved to the other side.

The use of actions in this case is counterproductive. If the touches generate a new position every frame, there isn't any movement going on but this results in the body being set to the given position. Try changing the code to set the player's position directly to see if that makes any difference.

Also note that move actions completely ignore the physics world. If you issue a move that goes from one side of the wall to the other, then the move action will continue to update the physicss body's position every frame, with the body then resolving its contacts along the way and it will eventually "quantum tunnel" from one side of the wall to the other.

Partially responsible for this problem may be the great distances between two touch locations when the user swipes quickly. You should perhaps use the physics world's bodyAlongRayStart:end: method to test if there's a blocking body between the current and target position (gesture translation) and if so, cancel the movement.